# Font-Awesome overlap icons

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I need to use icons for my ranking app.

I want to start with 5 empty stars icons using icon-star-empty.

and then to overlap them with icon-star to fill them up based on the rank.

font-awesome has only half empty star with missing half of the star.

does anyone know if I could overlap icons to accomplish my goal?

EDIT:
this is the code for 5 full empty star icons:

```
<i class="icon-star-empty icon-large"><i class="icon-star-empty icon-large"><i class="icon-star-empty icon-large"><i class="icon-star-empty icon-large"><i class="icon-star-empty icon-large"></i></i></i></i></i>
```

and i want to overlap it with this:`<i class="icon-star-half icon-large"></i>`
10x

Comment: A picture (and a block of code for that matter) paints a thousand words.

Comment: this is a general questions.
is it possible to overlay font-awesome icons?

Comment: I don't understand your goal.

Comment: Google it - Theres a general answer

Comment: Yes you can overlap images/divs with CSS.

Comment: font-awesome only has icon-star-half
i need full star icon half black half empty

Comment: How about you make your own star? Or find one that works on the interweb.

Comment: I really dont see your problem... Cant you just use icon-star-empty and icon-star?

Comment: I did not manage to get a half star black half star empty to get 2.5 stars for example.

Comment: To get the empty star behind the half full star just do: <i class="icon-star-empty"><i class="icon-star-half-empty"></i></i>

Comment: I've already tried it,this did not work
I'm getting 2 stars - 1 empty and 1 half

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understan right this is what you are trying to do:

```
<div id="empty">
<img class="stars empty" src="http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/icojoy/noshadow/standart/gif/24x24/001_17.gif">
</div>

<div id="half">
<img class="stars empty" src="http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/icojoy/noshadow/standart/gif/24x24/001_17.gif">
<img class="stars half" src="http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/icojoy/noshadow/standart/gif/24x24/001_16.gif">
</div>

<div id="full">
<img class="stars empty" src="http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/icojoy/noshadow/standart/gif/24x24/001_17.gif">
<img class="stars half" src="http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/icojoy/noshadow/standart/gif/24x24/001_16.gif">
<img class="stars starfull" src="http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/icojoy/shadow/standart/png/24x24/001_15.png">
</div>
```

I enclosed each case in a div.
To overlay the images the way you are trying, you need to have an absolute position assigned.
Here is a fast CSS that illustrates how it would then work for you:

```
div {
    position:relative;
    height:2em;
}
.stars {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
```

Hope this was what you were trying to do. You can apply this to any kind of html tag element and as many times you want, 10 times, 100 times =)

**Edit:**
I read your question and all comments one more time ... and I think you could do this easier just with changing backgrounds and/or using overlapping backgrounds instead of overlapping html elements.
I used your code from above and illustrated what i mean on fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/38vHj/

And anyway it is much easier to swap classes in javascript (or php or where ever you want to process the information) ... and then use specific css class selector.

**The final solution:**
So yes ... you can overlap any html tag elements!
Now after a lot of back and forth I wrote you exactly what you wanted and posted it on fiddle: [jsfiddle.net/ddXDp/2](http://jsfiddle.net/ddXDp/2)

So the end result is an additional empty star element under the half star element.
Now you just have to arrange and style the elements the way you wanted =)

Comment: 10x, can you apply your solution to font-awesome?

Comment: then it will be something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ddXDp/1/ if you need it to be nested like you did it in your example code ... but you probably had a reason why you did it like that =)

Comment: I finally got what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/ddXDp/2/, I added it to the answer too =D yay!

Comment: 10x.....this did the trick